# remove duplicate from one column and add its corresponding value

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have three columns with huge data, column one have id and column three have values. there is duplicates in id but not in values. i want to remove duplicates from id's column but want sum of all value.
for eg
    id class_code value
    a      =        1
    b      *       2
    c      +        3
    a      +        4
    d      =         5
    b      +        6
    a      =        7
    a      +        8
    b       *       9

want output like

```
a   8
a   12
b   11
c   3
d    5
```

only remove those which have same class_codes and id nd add there value, after this operation print entire list, also remove first row that have header.
i tried but its removing entire value from table

```
file="C:/Python25/ref.txt"
fh=open(file,'r')
myData=fh.read()
myText=myData.split()
line_seen=set()
for line in myText:
    if line in line_seen:
        line_seen.add(line)
            print line[0:]

fh.close()
```

Comment: "there is duplicates in id but not in values" That means value is the id and the id is the value.

Comment: You've tagged 2.7... but your post hints more towards Python 2.5 - you might wish to check that...

Comment: I think you should solve this with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
with open('your_file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.split()
        if line[0] in d:
            d[line[0]] += int(line[2])
        else:
            d[line[0]] = int(line[2])
```

1. Read the file line by line.
2. Insert into the dictionary if the `id` is not present.
3. Update the dictionary if the `id` is present.
4. BOOM! Done.

Comment: one thing that forget to mention that, there is a class code between id and values. like' a = 1,
b = 2,
c * 3,
a * 4,
d =  5,
b j  6,
a i 7,
a *  8,
b  =  9,. i want add values of those id whose class_codes are similar. sorry for incomplete information. first column have id,second with class codes and third contain values.

Comment: Not a problem. Use `line[2]` instead of `line[1]`. RTM on how `split()` works.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, when you use a dictionary. Something like this should work (not tested):

```
D = dict()
for line in myText:
    if line[0] not in D.keys():
        D[line[0]] = line[1])
    else
        D[line[0]] = D[line[0]] + line[1])
```

Comment: Never heard of `.put()` function for a dictionary. Its better to avoid function calls as much as possible. Also, this will not work since `line[1]` is a string, so numbers will get concatenated.

Comment: Yeah well, I don't have a Python compiler handy, but I'm sure it won't be that hard to make this work. I replaced the put().

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for line in open('ref.txt'):
    key, value = line.split()
    d[key] += int(value)

print sorted(d.items())
```

[('a', 20), ('b', 17), ('c', 3), ('d', 5)]

Comment: this is working for the value i have printed but not for huge amount of data

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? How huge is huge? Is the data set so big that your dictionary fills the available memory? Then an external DB is what you need.

Comment: showing this .                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python25/dict.pl", line 6, in <module>
    key, value = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: .split() is creating a tuple with more than 2 elements. So if you have three or more columns and want to ignore the third one: key, value = line.split()[:2]