# Data append in a list using the previous data in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

İ need to create a list in Python. It is a little complicated. The list will contain items which appends according to previous value. For example, suppose that my list contains

```
x : 11 (key, value pair)
y : 5
z : 6
```

if I want to add another "x" item with value "4", it will detect the previous value "11" of "x" and it will be recorded as " x : 15" as the sum with the previous one. I thought that I might use linked lists but I could not figure it out. Can you just provide me with other methods, data structures or code for this purpose?

Comment: `"Can you just provide me with"` No. If you want to be a programmer, then you should try programming. Not copy/pasting stuff people hack together for you on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19904834/1500692

Comment: i already stated that i used linked lists :). But i could not come to a solution. I dont need ready made code. I can do it by myself with the required material. In this situation, i dont have the material. First time i deal with this type of data manipulation. I researched but in the end i need help and ideas .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [{'x':11}, {'y':2}, {'z':3}]

def addItem(L, key, value):
    for index, element in enumerate(L):
        if key in element:
            L.remove(element)
            L.insert(index, {key, element[key] + value})        
    return L

L[:] = addItem(L, 'x', 4)
print(L)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and calling a function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def add_item(d, key, value):
    d[key] += value

d = defaultdict(int)
add_item(d, 'x', 11)
add_item(d, 'x', 4)
print d
>>> 
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'x': 15})
```

Comment: I just want to say that `d = defaultdict(int)` is the key point for resolving the priblem.